# Laravel 5.2 reading from header authtoken on apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am trying to use JWT authentication, but unable to read the authtoken.
If I send the token along the url it works fine, but in header it does not.
This link says if on Apache ,we need to configure the apache config. I did that as well but it's not working.
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

I tried changing in .htacess which comes along with Laravel 5.2 inside `public/`

My current .htaccess looks like this

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
   RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

</IfModule>
```

Am I missing something OR doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please the lines

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)`

`RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]`

Before

`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Complete .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried did not work!.  Can u provide the whole .htacess ?

Comment: i modified the answer

Comment: Try restarting apache, clear laravel's cache, post your php code that reads the header